# ElasticSearch Query on nested object

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following document structure:

```
           "IDNumberTypes": {
              "ID": [
                 {
                    "@IDType": "Company Identification No.",
                    "IDValue": [
                       {
                          "#text": "CompanyID"
                       }
                    ]
                 },
                 {
                    "@IDType": "Reg. Number",
                    "IDValue": [
                       {
                          "#text": "RegNumber"
                       }
                    ]
                 },
                 {
                    "@IDType": "Tax ID Number",
                    "IDValue": [
                       {
                          "#text": "TaxNumber"
                       }
                    ]
                 }
              ]
           }
```

I'm trying to write a query that matches TaxNumber but only in the context of "National Tax No.".
Something like this in pseudoSQL:

```
IDNumberTypes.ID.IDValue.#text="TaxNumber" WHERE IDNumberTypes.ID.@IDType="Tax ID Number"
```

Just doing it like this obviously results in returning documents that contain an object with "@IDType": "Tax Number"

```
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": {
        "match": {
           "IDNumberTypes.ID.IDValue.#text": {
              "query": "TaxNumber",
              "operator": "and"
           }
        }
     },
     "filter": {
        "match": {
           "IDNumberTypes.ID.@IDType": {
              "query": "Tax ID Number",
              "operator": "and"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

...but doesn't make sure that the object I'm looking for has to have this specific structure:

```
{
 "@IDType": "Tax ID Number",
 "IDValue": [{
              "#text": "TaxNumber"
             }]
}
```

How can I properly filter/construct my query?

I already sorted it out by adding a proper mapping:

```
{
   "mappings": {
     "doxx": {
       "properties": {
         "IDNumberTypes": {
           "properties": {
             "ID": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                 "@IDType": {
                   "type": "string"
                 },
                 "IDValue": {
                   "type": "nested",
                   "properties": {
                     "#text": {
                       "type": "string"
                     },
                     "@IDnotes": {
                       "type": "string"
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: May you please provide a bit more details: which ES version are you using? What is the mapping of your ES document?

Comment: I already sorted it out by adding a proper mapping:see OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper mapping:

```
{
   "mappings": {
     "doxx": {
       "properties": {
         "IDNumberTypes": {
           "properties": {
             "ID": {
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                 "@IDType": {
                   "type": "string"
                 },
                 "IDValue": {
                   "type": "nested",
                   "properties": {
                     "#text": {
                       "type": "string"
                     },
                     "@IDnotes": {
                       "type": "string"
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```